# List difference of Merged branches between two branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

For every feature/bug we create a new branch out of `production` branch, and merge to `development` branch for testing

Approved feature getting merged to `production` and Un-approved stayed at `development`(development-1.0) branch.

After lot of un-approved features, there was discrepancy b/w `production` and `development` branch.

So, we created a new `development`(development-2.0) branch out of `production`, and started merging on that.

Now, want to list the difference of branches that were merged to `development-1.0` and `development-2.0`

Comment: If you got the merged list from `development-1` and `development-2` ( `git switch development-1 && git branch --merged`) - could you compare those branch lists?  would that give you the answer?

Comment: @matt 
As an example, If branch A and B were merged to development-1.0.
Since branch A is approved, that is merged to production.
Now I created a new development-2.0 and merged Branch C onto that.
Then, can I get output as branch C

Comment: @matt Sorry for my bad english, please try to understand.

Branch C is actually the branch which is left over, and now i want to track all the feature/bug that were left over, to start work on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log` to list commits which are in one branch but not in another.

```
git log development-1.0..development-2.0 # commits in development-2.0 not in development-1.0
git log development-2.0..development-1.0 # commits in development-1.0 not in development-2.0
```